# Force simulation producing NaN coordinates for new node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm new to the D3.js framework and looking for help. I'm trying to draw a network using a simple force simulation. I want a new node added in every second and joining the simulation.

Below is my attempt. I'm starting the sim with two nodes, which behave nicely. However, when I add a third node, it gets assigned NaN values to both its x and y coordinates by the simulation.

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const height = +svg.attr('height');
const width = +svg.attr('width');

// Test Data
const nodes = [ {}, {} ];

setTimeout(() => {
  nodes.push({});
  redraw();
}, 2000);

const ticked = () => {
  svg.selectAll('g.node')
    .attr('transform', d => {
      if (isNaN(d.x) || isNaN(d.y)) {
        console.error('nan!!!');
        d.x = 50;
        d.y = 50;
      }

      return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`;
    });
};

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('repulsion', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-30))
  .force('pin_y_to_center', d3.forceY().y(d => height / 2).strength(0.1))
  .force('pin_x_to_center', d3.forceX().x(d => width / 2).strength(0.1));

simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.on('tick', ticked);

const redraw = () => {
  const node = svg
    .selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('g');

  node.attr('class', 'node')
    .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 5);
};

redraw();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the array to the simulation...

```
simulation.nodes(nodes);
```

... inside the `redraw` function.

Here is your code with that change only:

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');
const height = +svg.attr('height');
const width = +svg.attr('width');

// Test Data
const nodes = [{}, {}];

setTimeout(() => {
  nodes.push({});
  redraw();
}, 2000);

const ticked = () => {
  svg.selectAll('g.node')
    .attr('transform', d => {
      if (isNaN(d.x) || isNaN(d.y)) {
        console.error('nan!!!');
        d.x = 50;
        d.y = 50;
      }

      return `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`;
    });
};

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('repulsion', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-30))
  .force('pin_y_to_center', d3.forceY().y(d => height / 2).strength(0.1))
  .force('pin_x_to_center', d3.forceX().x(d => width / 2).strength(0.1));

simulation.on('tick', ticked);

const redraw = () => {
  simulation.nodes(nodes);
  const node = svg
    .selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('g');

  node.attr('class', 'node')
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5);
};

redraw();
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300"></svg>
```

Also, consider re-heating the simulation after appending the new node.